# How would I use the `click` function on a `div` element?

Tags: javascript

I tried to do

```
var js = document.getElementById('product16');
js.click
```

But that only works for buttons? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You can use the `click` function an any HTMLElement, it just does nothing if there is no click listeners. I'm not sure what the issue is, or what is the desired behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Instead of referencing the click function (`js.click`), try calling it: `js.click()`.

**NL;PR:** As Seblor mentioned, any HTML element allows event listeners binding.

This pastebin shows an alert triggered programmatically from a function bound to a div's click event.

```js
var js = document.getElementById('product16');
js.click = function (){alert("div click");}; // assign some behavior
js.click(); // trigger it
```

```html
<div id="product16">
hello
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the click function to simulate a click on an element so it would be like this

```js
var js = document.getElementById('product16');
js.click() // you need to call the click handler
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ae1yujkc/1/

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the question above ?

Comment: OP didn't call the click handler on the element

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!